# Why do my iPad and iPhone send *two* notifications for every gmail I receive?

Tags: ios, mail.app, gmail, notifications

Every time I get an email, I hear a ping and a vibration on my devices, followed by another about 3 seconds later.

I'm using gmail (through exchange) on both devices.  The only option I can find in settings is to turn 'new mail' notifications on or off.   I do not have other email accounts on the devices, so it's not auto-forwarding to two accounts or anything.

I'd like to get a single ping and or vibration for each message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the notification sound with each push event that results in a new message to any mailbox.

Google likes to send mail to All Mail as well as Inbox, so that is the likely cause of the two push events. You could make a temporary rule to skip the inbox for all messages and test to confirm this is the root cause.  The phone sees them as two messages, because they are in reality two messages arriving at different times to different mailboxes. I don't know a way to mark the All Mail always read, but perhaps the google filters are powerful enough to make this happen on your account.

Until (or if) google changes things to push them all at once, you can enable control over folders/tags in the labels settings. By controlling the ***Show in IMAP...*** status,  you should be able to avoid the second ding. 
[image]

You could also try setting up rules to avoid any one message from hitting more than one folder as an unread message. iOS doesn't ding on sync of read messages, just syncs that change the unread count on a folder.

Lastly, iOS has changed behavior of the mobile mail app in the past to work better with Google mail. It's a common complaint, and could also be fixed with a change to mail on iOS.

Comment: Correct. This is exactly the thing I'd suggest.

Comment: thanks - Is there a way to set it to not hit the "all mail" as unread?   I still want messages showing (and notifying) in the inbox as unread, because that's what I monitor, but I don't want to stop the message from going to "all mail" in imap, since I use that as a safety net for messages I've archived or deleted from my inbox that I later want to see from the mail app.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know how to make a filter process things based solely on their presence in all mail. There are easily hundreds of settings in gmail, so it might just be a matter of searching for that one check box. Perhaps someone else will have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It happened on my iPhone 6s as well. To fix it, just turn off the sound notification from Settings > Mail > Notifications and select exchange account.

You are getting two notifications because one is coming from phone notifications and the second one comes from the app notifications (so just disable the mail notification for your exchange account)

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

At first I thought it was iCloud's push. It is not! In your original iCloud set up it pushed the entire account so you have two of every email account.  Go to settings, email accounts and just delete the doubles.  That's it that's all.

Comment: He doesn't have iCloud, he said he has Gmail accounts.